# iOS Core Data Persistence for related entity

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, persistence

In my core data object model I have two entities that are related with a one to many relationship.

Example:
table A can have many table B's associated with it.

My question is, when I add table B rows (with the object reference to Table A), do I need to independently save table B, or will the save of Table A also persist table B?

It appears that table B is being persisted when table A is saved.. but I cannot find any documentation to confirm this.. and I want to make sure I don't run the risk of losing data.

(Core Data saves are very slow.. and saving Table B data independently is a hog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think about tables.  What gets saved is the managed object context, which translates into: any changes you've made to managed objects using that context.

Comment: Thanks Philip,  so for this example --> [self.myObject managedObjectContext]  save:&error].... any of the objects in that context will be saved... not just myObject?

Comment: Yeah, as Philip said you pull your data into a managed context object and you can show/add/delete whatever you want to this object including manipulating all entities (tables) and their child tables and parent tables... when you're done, you simply save call "save" on the context and everything you changed will be stored.

Comment: @mtb - Yes.  In that case, you're just using `myObject` as a convenient hook for getting the context.  Once you're sending it a message, how you got it is irrelevant.